# Need help DIV alignment(position) in css

Tags: css, joomla

I am developing joomla template and I have two div each has 2 divs.
        
         Border 
         Top Menu

```
    <div id='menu' class='span12' >
    <div id='mainmenu' class='span9'> Main Menu</div>
    <div id='search' class='span3'> Search </div>
    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap.min.css
Everything is fine, but my second(top-menu, search) div in each div(top, menu) are showing right after finishing my first div but under the top-border;
Here is my css style

```
#top
{
background-color: black;
height:40px;
}
#top-border
{
background-color: red;
height:30px;
float:left;
}
#top-menu
{
background-color: blue;
float:right;
height:30px;
}
#menu
{
background-color: purple;
height:50px;
}
#mainmenu
{
background-color: yellow;
height:40px;
}
#search
{

background-color: brown;
float:right;

height:40px;
}
#photo
{
background-color: green;
margin-right:-20px;
height:300px;
}
```

when I put width 100% in #top it works fine but the width is changed.
Any idea how to solve this without using width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

the grid has 12 columns and you are using 9+3..so the full grid. You should check for margin's in your divs, and set them to 0. That's usually why it's now working the way you expected to.